# Difference between two similar Linq statements

Tags: c#, linq

I am quite new to LINQ to SQL, and C# in general. I'm wondering if there is a significant difference between these two LINQ queries, specifically regarding including parameters in .Query() as opposed to the .Where() call:

```
_work.DocRepository
.Query()
.Where(l => !archivedDocs.Contains(l.DocID) && l.name == filter.Name)
```

vs.

```
_work.DocRepository
.Query(l => !archivedDocs.Contains(l.DocID))
.Where(l=>l.name==filter.Name)
```

Are there functional or performance issues to consider here?

Comment: This is not LINQ 2 SQL. There is no Query method there. Please correct tags. What LINQ provider is this?

Comment: Closing question because required information is missing.

Comment: Functionally they seem the same. Don't know what that `Query` method is about, but looks like it can filter results the same way `Where` does. Regarding performance, use a profiler and/or a stopwatch to find the answer.